# compare mouse position to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to make a hover like effect while dragging a div by getting the position of the mouse and compare i to some other divs. I tried something like this:

```
$("#ha").draggable({
drag: function () {
    $(this).removeClass("halla");
    $("#align").remove();
    $(".box").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("halla");
        if (event.pageX > $(this).position().left && event.pageX < ($(this).position().left + $(this).width()) && event.pageY > $(this).position().top && event.pageX < ($(this).position().top + $(this).height())) {
            $(this).addClass("halla");
        }
    });
}
});
```

A fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9yyKN/8/

 Every object behaves differently when the mouse i over it. Really strange. What am i doing wrong?

*Don't tell me to just use .hover()

Comment: THIS IS UNACCEPTABLE: `Don't tell me to just use .hover()`

Comment: You cannot drag others because you are using draggable only on id="ha". What about #ha1, #ha2, and #ha3???

Comment: hover is the best way.

Comment: I am not trying to drag the others.. Thank you for your great answers

Comment: Your question is not clear at all what are you trying to achieve?